# C# WPF Alternative for WebBrowser Control with FlashPlayer compatibility

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, flash

yeah I know. There are already enough questions for alternatives of the WebBrowser control, but I need to know if one of these alternatives is able to play flash-animations very fluently.
The problem of mine:
I have a server with 10 screens. On 3 of them I will present a WebBrowser control with a given Flash animation. If I start the animation on 1 screen, everything works fine. If I start it on a second one, the whole app begins to "stutter". When I start it on a third screen, it almost freezes.
If I start these in external Firefox-Browsers (or the like) everything works fine. So it has to do something with the control.

Every help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried spawning multiple threads to handle each instance of the web browser control? I could be wrong but it sounds to me like it's all running in one thread and hammering the GUI thread.

Comment: No... that didnt even came to my mind... but I could check on this. I'll tell you what I found out.

Comment: I've got a problem when I put those windows in different threads. I use this line inside the window:
var singleOrDefault = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
                .SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active);
But then I get these error messages: 
Application.Current.Windows made an exception of the type System.InvalidOperationExecption.
And inside this message there is a further information about that the windows cannot change the control, because the control is owned by another thread... thats becoming complecated.